# MomentJS return global is undefined after babel compile

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs, babeljs

I use fullCalendar plugin with MomentJS and after babel compilation, i've this error about MomentJS :

```
global is undefined
```

Do you have any idea where the problem could come ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the solution to this issue. I was getting an error on a different library than Moment. Heroku logs reported

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' in /app/node_modules/sentiment/lib

However, after babel compilation (via webpack) I got the same error in console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

When I prettified the compressed code, the error was being thrown on this line

> x=global.Object.prototype

Which I tracked back to the library lodash. Webpack uses lodash to run babel. Based on the information in [this conversation thread](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/915) the issue was resolved by updating lodash version to 4.13.1 from version 3.5.0.

Both the console error and the Module Not Found error went away.